# angularjs pass ngModel from wrapper directive to wrapped directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular and still painfully wrapping my head around custom directives.

I'd like to reuse this bit of HTML

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.selectedLanguages" multiple search-enabled="true" theme="select2" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="lang.id as lang in langs |filter: { name : $select.search }">
        <div ng-bind-html="lang.name | highlight: $select.search" ></div> 
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

by wrapping it into my custom directive:

```
<language-picker ng-model="model.selectedLanguages"/>
```

something like this:

```
app.directive('languagePicker', function() {
            return {
                template : '<ui-select ng-model="**PARENT'S NGMODEL**" multiple search-enabled="true" theme="select2" style="width: 300px;"><ui-select-match >{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match><ui-select-choices repeat="lang.id as lang in langs | filter: { name : $select.search }"><div ng-bind-html="lang.name | highlight: $select.search"></div></ui-select-choices></ui-select>',
                restrict : 'E',
                require : 'ngModel',
                replace : true
                    ....
            };
        });
```

But how do I pass the ngModel from my `language-picker` to the `ui-select` directive ?

**UPDATE**

Using the suggestions below, I got it work with ui-select, but the outer model doesn't get updated at all,see [plnkr.co/edit/Y43dmMGIc5GxM9fLoNPW](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y43dmMGIc5GxM9fLoNPW), probably because it's child scope and parent scope remains the same?

**UPDATE 2**

I got it to work in a convoluted way that looks horrible to me, because I've no idea why it "works" in the first place (see the weird stuff happening in the controller):

```
app.directive('languagePicker', function(LanguageService) {
            return {
                templateUrl : 'LanguagePickerTpl.html',
                restrict : 'E',
                scope : {
                    languages : '='
                }, 
                controller : function($scope, LanguageService) {
                    console.log($scope);
                    $scope.langs = LanguageService.get();
                    $scope.model = $scope;
                }

            };
        })
```

template:

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.languages" multiple search-enabled="true" 
  theme="select2" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match>{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="lang.id as lang in langs | filter: { name : $select.search }">
      <div ng-bind-html="lang.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

I would be very happy if anyone could explain what's going on  (the "working" example is here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/B53F9sc7UGkj0uxUpC17
)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the child scope has access to its parents properties without doing anything. The if you care for re-usability you should probably follow the answers described bellow, and pass the property in through an attribute on the child directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the "equals" syntax on you directive's scope. This will keep hold of the values populated in the parent scope.
So your directive becomes:

```
app.directive('languagePicker', function() {
        return {
            template : '<ui-select ng-model="**PARENT'S NGMODEL**" multiple search-enabled="true" theme="select2" style="width: 300px;"><ui-select-match >{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match><ui-select-choices repeat="lang.id as lang in langs | filter: { name : $select.search }"><div ng-bind-html="lang.name | highlight: $select.search"></div></ui-select-choices></ui-select>',
            restrict : 'E',
            require : 'ngModel',
            replace : true,
            scope: {
                ngModel: "=ngModel"
            }
            ...
        };
    });
```

I am confident this will work for you :)
Let me know if it does not!

Comment: Thanks, it works! at least it works with embedded `<input ng-model="..."/>` in template. With `ui-select`, I am not sure, as I've now bumped into the `multidir` error arising because I'm combining two directives with isolate scope, so there's stome more work ahead )

Comment: Actually I can't make it work with `ui-select`, the outer model doesn't get updated at all,see http://plnkr.co/edit/Y43dmMGIc5GxM9fLoNPW

Comment: I got it to work in an extremely convoluted way, and I have no idea why it works  http://plnkr.co/edit/B53F9sc7UGkj0uxUpC17

Comment: @AunAun well done. I did fork the plunk earlier and have a play but I had no joy. That looks great though from your new plunk!

Comment: I used ng-model="ngModel"

Answer (score 15):

The `ng-model` has some special handling, see [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) under the heading "Custom Control Example". The steps are:

1. I suggest you use isolated scope; it makes the interface to your component clearer and saves you from side-effects. In this case you want to pass the list of available options (languages):

   ```
   scope: {
       langs: '='
   }
   ```

   Usage would be:

   ```
   <language-picker ng-model="model.selectedLanguages" langs="langs"/>
   ```
2. Your directive requires (maybe optionally) the `ngModel`:

   ```
   require: ['ngModel']
   ```
3. You override `ngModel`'s `$render` method, e.g.:

   ```
   link: function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrls) {
       var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
       ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
           ...
       };
   }
   ```

   The logic of render is responsible for transferring the model value (the one here: `<language-picker ng-model="model.selectedLanguages"/>`, i.e. `model.selectedLanguages`) to the view. The simplest thing I can think of, is to **use isolated scope** and **transfer the outer model value to a variable of the isolated scope** as:

   ```
       ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
           scope.innerSelection = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
       };
   ```

   Bind this variable in the template as:

   ```
   <ui-select ng-model="innerSelection" ...>
       ...
   </ui-select>
   ```
4. Last you have to make sure that changes to the inner selection will be propagated to the outer model:

   ```
       // still inside link()
       scope.$watch('innerSelection', function(newval, oldval) {
           if( newval != oldval ) { // skip the first time
               ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newval);
           }
       });
   ```

This solution may be a bit more involved than others, but lets you use all the features of the `ngModel`, e.g. validation, parsing/formatting (i.e. data conversion).

Comment: `NgModelController.$render()` was the last missing piece of the puzzle for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass model.selectedLanguages as a property to the directive such as:

`< language-picker language="model.selectedLanguage" />`

And inside the directive use the language property.
You can decide upon which scope you need.

I also recommend using a templateUrl to the html document with that bit of code in it. It really makes life much easier. 
Then you can modify the html document to simply put ng-model="language" after editing your directive as suggested.

There really are plenty of examples in the official documentation.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in two different ways:

Given the following "call":

```html
      <div
        ng-model="myData"
        required
        boolean-select
      ></div>
```

Either using "replace: true":

```
  .directive('booleanSelect', function booleanSelect() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<select ' +
        'class="form-control" ' +
        'ng-options="v.value as v.label for v in yesNoOptions" ' +
        'ng-required="required"><option value="">Select</option></select>',
      replace: true,
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.required = $attrs.hasOwnProperty('required');

        $scope.yesNoOptions = [{
          value: true,
          label: 'Yes',
        }, {
          value: false,
          label: 'No',
        }];
      },
    };
  })
```

You **don't need to put** `ng-model` in the template as it's, well, replaced "inline", merging attributes from the "caller", so the caller's `ng-model` will be used.

Or, this way:

```
  .directive('booleanSelect', function booleanSelect() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<select ' +
        'class="form-control" ' +
        'ng-model="ngModel" ' +
        'ng-options="v.value as v.label for v in yesNoOptions" ' +
        'ng-required="required"><option value="">Select</option></select>',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=ngModel',
      },
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.required = $attrs.hasOwnProperty('required');
        $scope.yesNoOptions = [{
          value: true,
          label: 'Yes',
        }, {
          value: false,
          label: 'No',
        }];
      },
    };
  })
```

Here we don't replace, but we get the `ngModel` without requiring the controller at all, just as a scope value. Then we can use it in the template. We can't use replace because there would be a conflict of `ng-model`.

I personally prefer the first option! (and one less element in the dom).